# Is there a wireless video doorbell that will chime on Google Nest speaker?

Tags: smart-home, google-home, wireless, google-assistant, home-security

Most smart doorbells (e.g. [Google Nest Hello doorbell](https://store.google.com/gb/product/nest_hello_doorbell)) seem to require a wired connection. The Ring wireless doorbell looks like the most popular but [compatibility with Google Assistant looks poor](https://assistant.google.com/services/a/uid/000000e4ac17fd8b?hl=en-US). I can't tell if Ring would chime on Google Nest but it looks like I can only ask Assistant to tell me things rather than it proactively do them...

I want a wireless (i.e. battery powered and wifi) doorbell that chimes on my Google Nest speaker and I can also access video (separately, not on Google).

Answer (score 0):

Scroll down that link to Nest doorbell

It has WiFi for network connectivity, it just requires wired power.

Also expecting Ring (an Amazon company) to work well with it's main competitor's products is possibly asking a little much

Comment: Thanks for your answer @hardillb. I'm looking to find a doorbell that doesn't require wired power, like Ring. I don't expect Ring to work with Google but it's the only battery powered solution I am aware of.

Comment: Oh gosh, @Abbie, someone rang the doorbell last October and is still waiting at the door !  
Anyway, since this question got "refreshed" today, I was wondering if you'd considered IFTTT as an intermediary between the Nest system and one of the million doorbell IFTTT compatible switches available on the market.  Let us know... if you're still there !

Comment: Thanks @kaylanswaroop. I ended up getting a Ring stick up cam that's battery operated, putting that above the door, and buying a regular wireless doorbell for a button and chime!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want it to be wireless so that you don't lose it when the power goes down, I would recommend getting a UPS/APC and using the Google Nest Hello Doorbell.

[According to Google](https://support.google.com/googlenest/answer/9250901), the Nest Hello Doorbell never draws more than 9W.  With an APC like the [BE650G1](https://www.apc.com/shop/ca/en/products/APC-Back-UPS-650/P-BE650G1), that means you'll have power on your device for well over 6 hours, which should cover most power outages.